# Closest meaning of Soulmate, 運命の人 or 心の友?

Tags: english-to-japanese

Just a simple question, which one has the closest meaning of soulmate, **運命の人** or **心の友**? Are they interchangeable in Japanese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

運命の人 is used exclusively to refer to a romantic partner or (future) spouse with a lifelong bond with you. 心の友 is used to refer to a close friend, typically of the same sex, as the kanji suggests. They are not interchangeable at all in Japanese.

運命の人 is a relatively common phrase. On the other hand, 心の友 is rare except that a manga character [ジャイアン](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_characters#Takeshi_Goda) uses this often. When I hear 心の友, I can't help recalling the character, and I believe many native Japanese speakers are like me. See [image search results for 心の友](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=1942&p=%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%8B&meta=vc%3D). Some online glossaries define this as a ジャイアン語 ("Jaian-ese") term.

Comment: Is there anything you're aware of involving 意気投合?  Like maybe 意気投合の者 or something?

Comment: @istrasci I don't think so. It's almost always used as a (suru-)verb.

Comment: Thank you very much @naruto. I first heard 心の友 from Itsuwa Mayumi (五輪 真弓) song. Now I also recall hearing it too from Jaian-Doraemon as you mentioned.